# Azure DevOps Server 2019 Task Template Layout Change

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I have a requirement to change the layout of the Task in Azure DevOps Server 2019. I want to relocate the "Details" section under the "Staus" section. I tried using the Process editor via VS 2019. But doesn't work published WIT show no modifications. Can anyone guide me through this?

[image]

Layout change I did:
[image]

---

**Additional Note:**
I tried following the inherited process model but got stuck. According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-form?view=azure-devops-2019#open-settingsprocess) some links are missing on our DevOps Server 2019. I logged in as the administrator of the DevOps server. Please refer to the screenshot attached.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Azure DevOps, we do have two process models,On-premises XML process model and Inheritance process model.

For Azure DevOps Server 2019, you have a choice of process models. **When you create a project collection, you'll need to choose between On-premises XML process model and Inheritance process model.**

Using the Process editor via VS 2019 only apply to On-premises XML process model.

If you are using inherited process, you need to do the customization in web portal directly-- [Customize the web layout for a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-form?view=azure-devops#move-field)

More details about the customization of these two models:

- [About process customization and inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=agile-process)
- [On-premises XML process customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops-2019)

Comment: We were migrated to 2019 from 2015 and can’t remember which process model we selected or even prompted for. So since my on prem xml doesn’t work I think we’re on inherited model. So I will undo the changes and try using the web portal. Will this be fine?

Comment: @SurenSaluka Yes, suggest you give a test on it. At least, you could narrow down if the issue is related process model or not.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give a shot later and let you know how it went. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I tried but failed. Please refer to the "Additional Note" section of the question. I have updated it.